# Unary languages in $AC^0$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Barrington, Immerman, and Straubing state

> circuit complexity classes contain problems which are not computable at all in the ordinary sense (e.g., any unary language is in $\text{AC}^0$)

I'd appreciate clarification of this statement; it seems to imply that $\text{AC}^0$ contains even undecidable languages.

Could someone please point out my error, or explain what the authors might mean?

- Barrington, D.A.M., Immerman, N., and Straubing, H., [*On Uniformity within $NC^1$*](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/pub/bis.pdf), JCSS **41** 274–306, 1990.  doi: [10.1016/0022-0000(90)90022-D](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000%2890%2990022-D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the beginning of the sentence you quoted.  It says

> **In their non-uniform versions** these circuit complexity classes contain problems which are not computable at all in the ordinary sense (e.g., any unary language is in AC<sup>0</sup>).

The nonuniform version of AC<sup>0</sup> is defined as the class of problems which are decided by a (not necessarily uniform) family of boolean circuits of polynomial size and constant depth with unbounded fan-in.  Since there is no uniformity condition, you can use completely different circuits for different lengths, implying that you can decide any unary languages (including undecidable ones).  This is the motivation of the uniformity condition.  For detail, see Proposition 11.2 of *Computational Complexity* by Papadimitriou.